# Remove quick access toolbar from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

It seems I have a funny toolbar in windows explorer.

[image: toolbar above ribbon]

How do I get rid of it?

It seems I only have the option to move it "below the ribbon".

[image: toolbar below ribbon]

but I have not found how to make it disappear.

Comment: I had some different commentary but I had originally thought this question was with regards on how to remove [Quick Access](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4844-remove-quick-access-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html) from File Explorer, that can indeed be done, but removing the Quick Access Toolbar itself CANNOT be done.  It's now a feature of File Explorer, so the only solution, if you simply cannot stand a toolbar without any icons (which can be done but the dropdown icon remains) is to replace File Explorer with something else.

Comment: Can you make it an answer?

Comment: What part of that should be an answer, that it cannot be done without using a third-party shell, or you can remove the Quick Access from the list of shortcuts within File Explorer with a registry key?

Comment: That I cannot remove the Quick Access toolbar from windows explorer (if I dont remove quick access in total)